# For each line in a file, print fields from specific column to NF if those values are less than value in another field

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following format where the number of fields per row is variable:

```
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69270   234 69037   65565   69037
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69511   475 69037   65565   69037
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69761   725 69037   65565   69037
NC_000001.11_NM_001385640.1 942155  20  942136  924432  925922  930155  931039  935772 939040   939272  941144  942136  942410  942559  943253  943698  943908
```

For each line, I would like to print the first four fields. For the remaining fields ($5 to NF), I want to print the field if the values in those fields is less than the value in $4.

Example output:

```
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69270   234 69037   65565   
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69511   475 69037   65565   
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69761   725 69037   65565   
NC_000001.11_NM_001385640.1 942155  20  942136  924432  925922  930155  931039  935772 939040   939272  941144
```

I've tried to wrap my head around a number of different awk options and have failed miserably. New to awk and would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you say "the number of fields per row is variable": Is it still guaranteed that there are at least 4 fields per row? Can there be empty rows? How are the fields separated (spaces, tabs, combinations therof)? Can there be empty fields (stated e.g. in tab-separated files by two consecutive tabs)? Please edit your post to supplement this information.

Comment: Does the white space between fields in the input need to be preserved in the output?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about the white space in your output then all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    out = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4
    for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( $i < $4 ) {
            out = out OFS $i
        }
    }
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69270 234 69037 65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69511 475 69037 65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69761 725 69037 65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001385640.1 942155 20 942136 924432 925922 930155 931039 935772 939040 939272 941144
```

which you can pipe to `column` to visually align if you like:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2  69270   234  69037   65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2  69511   475  69037   65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2  69761   725  69037   65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001385640.1  942155  20   942136  924432  925922  930155  931039  935772  939040  939272  941144
```

Otherwise if you want the spacing in the output to look like the spacing in the input (i.e. what looks like 1 or more blanks for the first 4 fields and 2 or more for the rest of the fields) and assuming some lines might only have 4 or less fields then using any POSIX awk (for character classes and regexp intervals):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
match($0,/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}[^[:space:]]+/) {
    out = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( $i < $4 ) {
            out = out OFS $i
        }
    }
    $0 = out
}
{ print }
```

If the fields after $4 should be tab-separated:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69270   234 69037   65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69511   475 69037   65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69761   725 69037   65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001385640.1 942155  20  942136  924432  925922  930155  931039  935772  939040  939272  941144
```

or if they should be separated by blanks:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69270   234 69037   65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69511   475 69037   65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69761   725 69037   65565
NC_000001.11_NM_001385640.1 942155  20  942136  924432  925922  930155  931039  935772  939040  939272  941144
```

The above retains the white space between the first 4 fields so that'll just be whatever combination of tabs and/or blanks you have in your input, and then prints a tab before every 5th and subsequent field which you can use `column` to change to equivalent blanks if you like, both of which look like the input and output in your question.

I'm building a new string named `out` in  the loops above and assigning it to `$0` once after the loops rather than modifying `$0` or `$i` within the loops because each time you change `$i` awk has to re-build `$0` from it's fields, and each time you change `$0` awk has to resplit `$0` into fields so both are inefficient and can lead to unexpected errors depending on the contents of the fields and therefore you should not modify `$0` or `$i` within a loop unless you have a very specific purpose in mind that requires you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This has been tested with GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0
Because of using 4th argument in `split` this solution might not work on other versions not compatible with syntax used here.

```
awk '{n=split($0, a, " ", b); line=""; for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { if (i < 5 || a[i] < $4) line=(line a[i] b[i])}; print line; }' file.txt
```

Explanation:

- `n=split($0, a, " ", b);` - this splits entire line (`$0`) into values (stored in `a`) and spaces (stored in `b`) so we can try to preserve formatting of original file. Value stored in `n` gives us number of fields to process each line. `split` arrays `a` and `b` indexes starts with 1.
- `line=""` - start with line as empty string
- `for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)` - lets iterate over each field, split starts with index 1 so do our loop. `<=` part ensures last (nth) field is also processed
- `if (i < 5 || a[i] < $4)` - condition is true for first 4 fields or whenever field value is less than fourth field (your required condition)
- `line=(line a[i] b[i])` - join actual field and spaces with previous ones that have met requirements of "if" condition
- `print line` - prints `line` variable that contains our desired output

Answer (score 0):

This iterates over the fields from the end of the line to the beginning (i.e. in reverse order) and deletes the field if the field number (`NF`) is greater than 4 **AND** the value of that field is greater than the value of field 4 (`$4`).

```
$ awk '{
    for (i=NF; i>=1; i--) {
      if ((i > 4) && ($i >= $4)) {
        $i=""
      }
    };
    print
    }' input.txt
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69270 234 69037 65565 
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69511 475 69037 65565 
NC_000001.11_NM_001005484.2 69761 725 69037 65565 
NC_000001.11_NM_001385640.1 942155 20 942136 924432 925922 930155 931039 935772 939040 939272 941144
```

BTW, it's not clear whether your input is space or tab separated. if you want tab-separated output (rather than a single space between each field), then add `-v OFS='\t'` to the awk command immediately before the single-quote starting the script.  e.g.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '...awk script here...' input.txt
```

BTW, awk will leave a lot of extra field separators in the output line, one wherever a field used to be before it was deleted.  If you want to get rid of those, add the following line immediately before the `print` statement:

```
    $0=$0; $1=$1;
```

This will effectively remove any empty fields, by forcing awk to re-evaluate the input line and split it into fields again (splitting on FS, the field-separator, which defaults to any amount of white-space). It's a bit of a hack because awk doesn't have any way to actually delete a field from a line, so you have to force it to do that after the line has been modified.